# Refactor code into a subfunction in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring

If they're a built-in function or extension in VS Code to refactor any selected code into a subfunction? Or at least to analyse the code and show all dependencies/variables that would need to be provided as function parameters. I know such a functionality from Pycharm.

My least goal would be to see in advance how much effort it would be to create a subfunction - or if it is meaningful at all (without providing dozens of parameters).

I am talking about Python.

Comment: Here's an idea... Refactor the code in PyCharm and then continue working on it in VSCode

Comment: Haha, that is good! No, there is a reason why I am not able to use Pycharm. And I like vscode. Since almost all functionality is somehow doable with extensions I wondered if this one is possible too.

Comment: Is [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_refactoring) what you're looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Great! It only works if the first line in the selection is a line of code. In my tests the first line always was a comment and then the light bulb is not shown.

Comment: Sure, it's well earned :) Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read document about [Python Refactoring](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_refactoring).

The Python extension adds the following refactoring functionalities: **Extract Variable, Extract Method and Rename Module**. It also supports extensions that implement additional refactoring features such as **Sort Imports**.

[image]

After selecting the code, you can click on the yellow light bulb on the left to  automatic refactoring.